# Adding a datatable to a database programmatically VB.NET

Tags: database, vb.net, datatable

I am trying to add a datatable to a database.  Here's what I've been trying:

```
    Dim newDataTable As DataTable = New DataTable("Example")
    VocabularyDataSet.Tables.Add(newDataTable)
    SqlDataAdapter1.Fill(VocabularyDataSet.Tables("Example"))
```

I've tried various incarnations of Fill and Update.  But the tables will not save on the database!

Any ideas?

Comment: I have used this before to create tables, it is written in C# that is why I am submitting it as a comment: http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/01/27/2775.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use [create table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) with a SQLCommand or OLECommand:

```
Dim cnn as SqlConnection = new SqlConnection("")
Dim cmd as SqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Create Table TableName (ID int, Name nvarchar(50), constraint PK_Table1 Primary Key (ID))", cnn)

cnn.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cnn.Close()
```

With datatable and dataset variables, you can just create table variables... not to attach them to your database...

Answer (score 3):

You need to execute a `CREATE TABLE` statement on the server using a `SqlCommand`.    (`DataAdapter`s will only populate tables, not create them)